# CakePHP: afterFind is weird with associations

Tags: cakephp, associations

So afterFind works fine and dandy when I'm within the corresponding model/controller. However, when calling an associated model, the data sent to the afterFind callback is formatted differently. This causes afterFind to crap out because it can't find the same array indexes it did when just working within the original model/controller.

Anyone know why, or what a fix might be?

Answer (score 3):

`$primary` may not be very helpful; I've found that it is always `false` when using ContainableBehaviour beyond the first depth:

```
$this->Model->find('first', array(
  'contain' => array(
    'SecondaryModel' => array(
      'TertiaryModel',
    ),
  ),
));
```

If you're setting a value based on a related model, you can check for its presence to deal with either structure like this:

```
function afterFind($results, $primary) {
  if (isset($results['TertiaryModel'])) {
    $results['secondary_model_field'] = 'value';
  }
  else {
    foreach ($results as &$result) {
      if (is_array($result) && isset($result['TertiaryModel'])) {
        $result[$this->alias]['secondary_model_field'] = 'value';
      }
    } unset($result);
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Alternately you may be able to just check for the location of a field on the model itself.  If the field doesn't exist at the top level, you will need to iterate over the set of results.

Comment: Additionally, I've found that `$primary==false` doesn't *necessarily* mean that the data is formatted differently than if it were true. It might be, but it depends on the find.

Comment: So is this issue still unresolved? For me, sometimes afterFind $results returns a multi-dimensional array, sometime it returns a key-value array. And as stated here, the $primary flag is always false because I am using containable. Any update on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote this answer in relation to CakePHP 1.3, but I don't think anything has changed in 2.0.  
The only solution is to check for the presence of a known key to determine if the result is a single result or set of results, and operate on them appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16159420/120080 offers a solution that seems like a good way to prevent the code duplication that my snippet requires

Answer (score 2):

This is what the second parameter to `afterFind` callback is for.

`$primary` tells if you if the find was called from this model directly (*true*), or if it was called by an associated model (*false*).

A note from the book:

> The $primary parameter indicates whether or not the current model was
>   the model that the query  originated on or whether or not this model
>   was queried as an association. If a model is queried  as an
>   association the format of $results can differ;
>
> Code expecting $primary to be true will probably get a "Cannot use
>   string offset as an array" fatal  error from PHP if a recursive find
>   is used.

So you may need different processing logic depending on the value of `$primary`

Comment: I check the primary and in 2 different scenarios I got primary false and the results structure is different. the only way I think I can solve it is like what people here suggest to check the structure of the results.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Cake 2.6 includes [a fix for this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4223), ensuring that all `$results` arrays are consistently formatted. I've done a little testing with the RC release and it does seem to work, with arrays all being passed in the format `{n}.ModelName.data`.

The fix is enabled by default, but you can also revert to the legacy behaviour if need be. Just add the following to your model (or AppModel) definition:

```
public $useConsistentAfterFind = false;
```