# CakePHP 2.x: Is the $primary flag on Model::afterFind() actually useful?

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP's `Model::afterFind()` callback looks like:

```
afterFind(array $results, boolean $primary = false)
```

According to the documentation:

> The `$primary` parameter indicates whether or not the current model was the model that the query originated on or whether or not this model was queried as an association. If a model is queried as an association the format of `$results` can differ.

They *can* differ, but experimentation shows that they don't *always* differ. As far as I can tell, the `$primary` parameter isn't actually all that useful. If it's set to `false` you may or may not get a flattened data structure, so you may or may not wind up with the dreaded "cannot use string offset as an array" error message.

Although I haven't tried it yet, my thought based on the documentation was to ignore the `$primary` flag altogether and just check the data:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
  if (array_key_exists(0, $results) {
    // operate on $results[0]['User']['fieldname']
  } else {
    // operate on $results['fieldname']
  }
  return $results;
}
```

This is hackish and I don't like it, but it seems likely to be more useful than `$primary`.

Explicitly stated, my questions are:

1. What is the `$primary` flag actually useful for?
2. Am I correct that it is *not* useful for determining the structure of the `$results` array, or have I missed something there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed the `$primary` parameter seems to only be useful in warning you of cases where the format of `$results` is unpredictable. It is not useful in determining the format of `$results`.

More information here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/Mqufi67UoFo

The solution offered there is to check `!isset($results[$this->primaryKey])` to see what format `$results` is. This is also a bit of a hack, but arguably better than checking for a key '0'.

The solution I ultimately came up with is to do something like this:

```
public function afterFind($results, $useless) {

    // check for the primaryKey field
    if(!isset($results[$this->primaryKey])) {
        // standard format, use the array directly
        $resultsArray =& $results;
    } else {
        // stupid format, create a dummy array
        $resultsArray = array(array());
        // and push a reference to the single value into our array
        $resultsArray[0][$this->alias] =& $results;
    }

    // iterate through $resultsArray
    foreach($resultsArray as &$result) {
        // operate on $result[$this->alias]['fieldname']
        // one piece of code for both cases. yay!
    }

    // return $results in whichever format it came in
    // as but with the values modified by reference
    return parent::afterFind($results, $useless);
}
```

This reduces code duplication because you don't have to write your field alteration logic twice (once for an array and once for non-array).

You may be able to avoid the references stuff altogether by just returning `$resultsArray` at the end of the method, but I wasn't sure what issues that might cause if CakePHP (or some other parent class) expects `$results` in the way it was passed in. Plus this way doesn't have the overhead of copying the `$results` array.

Comment: Ran into this problem today. Sometimes the $results set is a multi-dimensional array, sometime it's not. I feel like this should be a pretty big issue.

Comment: Wow I could kiss you. This just saved me after banging my head for 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't always rely on `primaryKey` being in the fields list AND you know the key you are looking for, you can get away with something a bit more simple. Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Decrypt password
 *
 * @see Model::afterFind()
 */
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {        
    if (!empty($results['password'])) {
        $results['password'] = Security::rijndael($results['password'], Configure::read('encrypt.key'), 'decrypt');
        return $results;
    }

    foreach ($results as &$r) {
        if (!empty($r[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $r[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::rijndael($r[$this->alias]['password'], Configure::read('encrypt.key'), 'decrypt');
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. The accepted answer works good. However, I had to make a minor adjustment. If you're looking to modify a field for example construct a fully qualified file name from logo, it's better to create a new field, as "return parent::afterFind($results, $useless);" will do it twice if the model find is called from some other model.

```
foreach($resultsArray as &$result) {
        // operate on $result[$this->alias]['fieldname']
        // one piece of code for both cases. yay!

        // Added logoFull instead of modifying logo
        if(isset($result[$this->alias]['logo'])){
            $result[$this->alias]['logoFull'] = Configure::read('urlImg') . 'logos' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                'carrier' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result[$this->alias]['logo'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Answers in the book...

> The $primary parameter indicates whether or not the current model was
>   the model that the query originated on or whether or not this model
>   was queried as an association. If a model is queried as an association
>   the format of $results can differ;
>
> Code expecting $primary to be true will probably get a "Cannot use
>   string offset as an array" fatal error from PHP if a recursive find is
>   used.

Thus it could be useful in certain situations for logic processing and may could be used to have a knock on effect into your $results

Comment: You may notice I quoted that same section of documentation. However, as I said in my question, if `$primary` is set to `false` that doesn't necessarily mean that `$results` will be formatted any differently. As the docs say, "the format of `$results` **can** differ." But then again, it might not. Experimentation supports this.