# cakePHP 2 afterFind for Model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I inherited code and in the Model the previous developer used the afterFind, but left it open when afterFind is executed in case of many to many relation to that table. So it works fine when getting one element from that Model, but using the relations break it.

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($results[$key]['Pitch'])) {
            if (isset($results[$key]['Pitch']['expiry_date'])) {
                    if($results[$key]['Pitch']['expiry_date'] > time()) {
                            $results[$key]['Pitch']['days_left'] = SOMETHINGHERE;
                    } else {
                            $results[$key]['Pitch']['days_left'] = 0;
                    }
            } else {
                    $results[$key]['Pitch']['days_left'] = 0;
            }
```

To solve this issue I added that code after the 2nd line.

```
//                    if (!isset($results[$key]['Pitch']['id'])) {
//                        return $results;
//
```

Is there a better way to solve that? I think afterFind is quite dangerous if not used properly.

Comment: that Model? after the 2nd line? afterFind? previous developer? = relations break it.

Comment: I edited to have the afterFind function. The example in the official documentation is http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html which is quite similar, but still doesn't handle in case you get back an array (many to many).
The previous developer is from an agency that developed it to the company I work now and I'm quite new with cakePHP. I used Symfony and plain PHP before.

Comment: The Model is cakePHP Model for Pitch which has many to many relation with another Model.

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but this may address the issue at hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106283/